# How to show up the images on tableview on Xamarin studio?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I was trying to some way but that don't success. That such as:

1. cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile (tableItems [indexPath.Row].artwork_url);// artwork_url is a images on website.
2. cell.ImageView.Image=UIImage.FromFile("/Photos/icon100x100.png");
3. I don't install SDKWebimage by nuget on xamarin studio. It's version is 1.0.0.

all ways in below are not run.
TableView just show **cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems [indexPath.Row].title;**.
That's not images.

I want to show this a images: ell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile (tableItems [indexPath.Row].artwork_url);// artwork_url is a images on website.

Please someone fix it. I'm new on xamarin studio for ios.

```
public async override Task<UITableViewCell> GetCell ( UITableView tableview, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableview.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

        if (cell != null) {
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
        } else {

            cell.ImageView.Image= await this.LoadImage(tableItems[indexPath.Row].artwork_url);
            cell.TextLabel.Text=tableItems[indexPath.Row].title;

        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have an async method to download the image fist before display

```
public async Task<UIImage> LoadImage (string imageUrl)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Task<byte[]> contentsTask = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (imageUrl);

        // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
        var contents = await contentsTask;

        // load from bytes
        return UIImage.LoadFromData (NSData.FromArray (contents));
    }
```

And you load the image with

```
LoadImage (tableItems [indexPath.Row].artwork_url).ContinueWith((task) => InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        cell.ImageView.Image = task.Result;
    }));
```

Comment: That got error: "the return type of an async method must be void, Task, or Task<T> at
public async override UITableViewCell GetCell ( UITableView tableview, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)